# Using filehandles in Perl to alter actively running code

Tags: perl, file-handling

I've been learning about filehandles in Perl, and I was curious to see if there's a way to alter the source code of a program as it's running. For example, I created a script named "dynamic.pl" which contained the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $append, ">>", "dynamic.pl");
print $append "print \"It works!!\\n\";\n";
```

This program adds the line

```
print "It works!!\n";
```

to the end of it's own source file, and I hoped that once that line was added, it would then execute and output "It works!!"

Well, it does correctly append the line to the source file, but it doesn't execute it then and there.

So I assume therefore that when perl executes a program that it loads it to memory and runs it from there, but my question is, is there a way to access this loaded version of the program so you can have a program that can alter itself as you run it?

Comment: As I mention in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37096010/14660), you can do this but it's a *major* security hole. What problem are you trying to solve with this? There's probably a better solution.

Comment: It's not for anything in particular, I was just curious to see if it would work. The eval function isn't quite what I was going for, because I wanted it to more than just execute the print function. I thought if someone was really clever they could work something like this into making a program that can reprogram itself over time.

Comment: The code written in a module can be manipulated in that way, by reloading that module. See my answer.   If it's just for play :)

Comment: @TallChuck You can! Subroutines can be replaced at runtime. Instead of single statements, `eval` entire subroutines.

Comment: @TallChuck I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37096010/14660) with an illustration of replacing subroutines.

Comment: @Schwern ah okay interesting, I didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a warning about all kinds of issues, you can reload modules.

There are packages for that, for example, [Module::Reload](http://search.cpan.org/~neilb/Module-Reload-1.10/lib/Module/Reload.pm).  Then you can write code that you intend to change in a module, change the source at runtime, and have it reloaded.

By hand you would delete that from `%INC` and then `require`, like

```
# ... change source code in the module ...
delete $INC{'ModuleWithCodeThatChages.pm'};
require ModuleWithCodeThatChanges;
```

The only reason I can think of for doing this is experimentation and play.  Otherwise, there are all kinds of concerns with doing something like this, and whatever your goal may be there are other ways to accomplish it.

**Note**   The question does specify a filehandle. However, I don't see that to be really related to what I see to be the heart of the question, of modifying code at runtime.

Comment: interesting, I'll look into that. Maybe I wasn't very clear with my question, but you seem to be the only one who understood what I was going for.

Comment: @TallChuck  This is the only way I know of to do what you are asking  -- to actually modify code that runs, not just read in new code.  (Which is why I didn't mention eval.)  However, you _did_ ask about filehandles. Is that critical, do you insist on involving filehandles in some particular way?

Comment: @zdim Good mention of Module::Reload. However you do mention `eval` indirectly. `require`, loading or reloading a module, is reading a file and `eval`ing it.

Comment: @Schwern  Well, yes.  But it is a module, which is loaded at start so it _is_ a part of the running program to be altered.  I meant with my comment that I didn't go for `eval`-ing _other_ code.  Is that what you mean, about the comment I made?  Thank you very much for commenting. Yes, I see, the comment is sloppy.  Should've been far more precise.  Thank you.

Comment: @zdim I just brought in filehandles because that was what got me thinking about it in the first place. I thoought "If I can edit other files, why can't I edit my source code...with my source code?"

Comment: @zdim `use` happens during compilation *of that particular unit*, but `require` happens at runtime. Yes, I'm being picky, but with a point: `eval` itself isn't evil. We use `eval` all the time to load modules, but it's restricted to files in `@INC` and hopefully those directories are trusted. It's the source of the thing you're evaling that's evil and exploitable. This is *in no way* an encouragement to use `eval` in production.

Comment: @Schwern Agree completely with all of it. I use eval (via require) all the time to selectively load modules (after BEGIN, at runtime per need). What I meant with distinguishing between them is about re-loading a module, so changing source code that already runs (vs. inserting new code). Of course, that is eval-ing too, thankj you for pointing it out.  Any and all of this, clearly, is with the understanding that it is only for play.

Answer (score 3):

The missing piece you need is [`eval EXPR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html). This compiles, "evaluates", any string as code.

```
my $string = q[print "Hello, world!";];
eval $string;
```

This string can come from any source, including a filehandle.

It also doesn't have to be a single statement. If you want to modify how a program runs, you can replace its subroutines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

sub speak { return "Woof!"; }
say speak();

eval q[sub speak { return "Meow!"; }];
say speak();
```

You'll get a `Subroutine speak redefined` warning from that. It can be supressed with `no warnings "redefine"`.

```
{
    # The block is so this "no warnings" only affects
    # the eval and not the entire program.
    no warnings "redefine";
    eval q[sub speak { return "Shazoo!"; }];
}
say speak();
```

Obviously this is a *major* security hole. There is many, many, many things to consider here, too long for an answer, and I *strongly* recommend you not do this and find a better solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve this way.

One way to mitigate the potential for damage is to use the [Safe](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe) module. This is like `eval` but limits what built in functions are available. It is by no means a panacea for the security issues.

Answer (score 0):

The source file isn't used after it's been compiled.

You could just `eval` it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $code = <<'__EOS__'
print "It works!!\n";
__EOS__

open(my $append_fh, ">>", "dynamic.pl")
   or die($!);
print($append_fh $code);
eval("$code; 1")
   or die($@);
```

Answer (score -1):

There's almost definitely a better way to achieve your end goal here. BUT, you could recursively make exec() or system() calls -- latter if you need a return value. Be sure to setup some condition or the dominoes will keep falling. Again, you should rethink this, unless it's just practice of some sort, or maybe I don't get it!

Each call should execute the latest state of the file; also be sure to close the file before each call.

i.e.,

`exec("dynamic.pl");` or

```
my retval; 
retval = system("perl dynamic.pl");
```

Don't use eval ever.

Comment: yeah I thought about something like that but the point isn't to re-execute the whole program, I want any program that implements this to be able to continue running as normal.

Comment: Gotcha. Wrapping the entire file-contents in `eval` will re-execute it anyways, so be sure to add some comment identifiers in your code above where you want to begin to execute, and then regex to that spot. Otherwise, you could be importing modules n+ times, and n+ errors