# Reload a perl script while running if the modification time changes

Tags: perl

I have a perl script running at any given time and triggering another perl script if a specific condition is met else it sleeps for 1 min.
Every time I have to make a modification to the main script and re-run it, I have to ensure no sub-script is running and then kill it and re-run.

So, have been looking if I can reload the perl script automatically based on the modification time. 
I came across the below link (code snippet shared below) and it works. But wondering, if this is the right way to do it? Any pointers?

Code Snippet here:
(test.pl keeps on running and Worker.pm can be modified  as needed)

Worker.pm:

```
    package Worker;

our $iteration = 1;

sub do_some_work {
    return if $iteration > 100;
    printf "$iteration Original\n";
    $iteration++;
    sleep 1;
    return 1;
}

sub save_state {
    return $iteration;
}

sub load_state {
    my $class = shift;
    $iteration = shift;
}
1;
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib '.';
use Worker;

my $library_file = $INC{'Worker.pm'};
my $library_mtime = ( stat( $library_file ) )[9];

while ( Worker->do_some_work() ) {
    my $new_mtime = ( stat( $library_file ) )[9];
    next if $new_mtime == $library_mtime;

    $library_mtime = $new_mtime;

    eval {
        my $state = Worker->save_state();
        delete $INC{'Worker.pm'};
        require 'Worker.pm';
        Worker->load_state( $state );
    };
}
```

Source  from: https://www.depesz.com/2015/01/21/reloading-of-perl-script-while-its-running/

Comment: See [again](https://metacpan.org/pod/again).

Comment: Apologize for referring directly to the link, have pasted the content here.

Comment: Is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37096022/4653379) what you are looking for?  (I don't understand the problem description fully.)

Comment: Thanks @SinanÜnür for the pointer to again module.

Comment: @zdim: I meant that in cases when I have to re-run the perl script upon modification, I can't end up aborting the script rightaway and re-run but have to wait for the second script called from within the main script to finish execution (which could take about an hour or so). So if the code could be automatically modified such that the second script continues executing.

Comment: That's getting a little nasty (while interesting for experimentation).  Can you then `fork` the second script?  (I would invest effort into solving the problem in a way that doesn't involve re-loading code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to restart the entire program.

Without external help (doesn't properly exit)

```
exec($^X, $0);
```

With external help (exits properly)

```
exit(254);
```

plus

```
#!/bin/sh
while true ; do
   program "$@"
   e=$?
   if [[ $e != 254 ]] ; then
      exit $e
   fi
done
```